# I have time series data with the dates in YYYYMX where X refers to the months from 1 to 12. I want to convert to YYYY-XX where XX is a numbero

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, replace, type-conversion

What I am coding is:

```
df = pd.read_excel("Ahiakpor.xlsx", index_col = 0)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(
    df.index
    .str.replace("M1", "-01")
    .str.replace("M2", "-02")
    .str.replace("M3", "-03")
    .str.replace("M4", "-04")
    .str.replace("M5", "-05")
    .str.replace("M6", "-06")
    .str.replace("M7", "-07")
    .str.replace("M8", "-08")
    .str.replace("M9", "-09")
    .str.replace("M10","-10")
    .str.replace("M11","-11")
    .str.replace("M12","-12")
)
```

The string is the date eg. 2001M1. I want it to be 2001-01. It is throwing this error:

```
ParserError: Unknown string format: 2000-010
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the format while parsing the strings. Pandas will automatically use the format to infer dates from the strings

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%YM%m').dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

---

```
# df.index

0    2000-01
1    2000-02
...
2    2000-10
3    2000-11
3    2000-12
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input string is `"2023M12"`, you replace `M1` by `-O1`, resulting in `"2023-012"`.

Reversing the order of the `str.replace` calls would likely fix the problem, but that's a fragile and ugly solution.

You could use a regular expression to replace the `-MX` pattern only at the end of the string -- and you could match on `-M<digit>` or `-M1<digit>` rather than enumerating all 12 possible strings.

But [Shubham Sharma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77608167/827263) is probably a better solution; it deals specifically with date strings rather than general strings, and so is likely less error-prone.